# How to find, load and use a legacy Mathematica package

Tags: packages, number-theory, compatibility

#### Question:

- How to find, load and use a legacy Mathematica package from a previous Mathematica version? What is the preferred approach and process?

#### Context:

I am working through a set of examples in Mathematica. One example being:

- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/Combinatorics/CoinProblem.nb

The problem is that the example given is from 2007 and relies upon:

```
<< NumberTheory`Frobenius`
```

in theory I could update the code and replace `FrobeniusF[]` with `FrobeniusNumber[]`, whilst also replacing `GreedyDecomposition[` with `FrobeniusSolve[`.

The above will work but it would be simpler to be able to find and use the original Mathematica package. Interested how people approach this type of problem as (I assume) it occurs with some level of frequency.

All help and advice gratefully received.

#### FrobeniusF Compatibility ref:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/NumberTheory/Frobenius.html

Comment: For what it's worth, if you search "Greedy Decomposition" in the Wolfram Documentation, the function [`NumberDecompose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberDecompose.html) shows up.  Do you think `GreedyDecomposition` is now `NumberDecompose`?

Comment: @QuantumDot Your help is worth a lot and very much appreciated. Your reference led me through a set of routes in the documentation to `FrobeniusSolve[`. I updated the question to reflect the reference.

Comment: Ah, so I was wrong.

Comment: @QuantumDot - Chuckle - you pointed me in the right direction.